# when does php json_decode return false?

Tags: php, json

In the PHP documentation for [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it says it can return `TRUE`,`FALSE`,`NULL`.

Could some help me understand when it would return `FALSE`? I understand invalid JSON will return `NULL`, but when would the other two be returned if not the actual JSON value?

Thanks

Comment: From what I can see, it would only return `TRUE` or `FALSE` if that was the actual value decoded.

Comment: it doesn't say that it returns true or false

Comment: "if not the actual JSON value" Sorry but what makes you believe `true` or `false` could be returned in any other case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**JSON format definition**](http://www.json.org/) clearly shows all possible values and their representations:

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or `true` or
>   `false` or `null`, or an object or an array.

Both objects and arrays have special syntax in JSON representation (wrapped in `{}` and `[]` respectively), so they can't be mixed up with `false` in any case. The same goes with string - it's wrapped in `""` (double quotation marks). As for Numbers, they have to contain at least one digit - so cannot be confused with `false` (and `true` and `null`) too.

So that leaves us with the only case: when json_encode processes an object having redefined its JSON representation. For example (PHP 5.4+):

```
class FalsyFoo implements JsonSerializable {
  public $foo;

  public function __construct($f) {
    $this->foo = $f;
  }

  public function jsonSerialize() {  
    return false; 
  }
}

$f = new FalsyFoo(true);
$fj = json_encode($f);
var_dump( $fj ); // string(5) 'false'
var_dump( json_decode($fj) ); // bool(false)
```

Technically, we still work with `false` value here, but the source is obviously different.

---

If you're still not convinced, check [the source code](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/json/json.c#788) of `json_decode`, which calls [php_json_decode_ex](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/json/json.c#664) after checking the arguments. This, in turn, calls [parse_JSON_ex](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/json/JSON_parser.c#439) first, which operates over the predefined [state transition table](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/json/JSON_parser.c#145); the latter has only one set of states leading to `false` value as result. If this call fails somehow, value is checked [directly](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/json/json.c#700):

```
if (str_len == 4) {
  if (!strcasecmp(str, "null")) {
    /* We need to explicitly clear the error 
         because its an actual NULL and not an error */
    jp->error_code = PHP_JSON_ERROR_NONE;
    RETVAL_NULL();
  } else if (!strcasecmp(str, "true")) {
    RETVAL_BOOL(1);
  }
} else if (str_len == 5 && !strcasecmp(str, "false")) {
  RETVAL_BOOL(0);
}
```

... and that's the only case when return_value is set to boolean.

Comment: haha... but is this the only way? I'm wondering when it would not return something other than `NULL` or the json value itself

Comment: In other words, you're asking how can `false` value be encoded in any other way than as a string 'false' (case-insensitive)?

Comment: Updated the answer. Sorry, I always thought it's kind of obvious that `false` value cannot be represented as anything else but `false` literal. ) Remember, expressions are not encoded: their results are.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that `values true, false and null (case-insensitive) are returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL respectively.` This means that if the booleans `true` or`false` are in the object to be encoded, they will be shows as `TRUE` or `FALSE`, and the same for null. For example:

```
json_decode('["hello",true]');
```

would return:

```
["hello",TRUE]
```

It doesn't mean that `json_decode` will return values of `true`, `false`, or `null`

Comment: i did read the question, and you said nothing about incorrectly interpreting the documentation and you didn't comment about it either. So, in other words, you downvoted my answer for no reason